# Using 'itemgetter' to sort on last, first name in a tuple from a dictionary?

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

My programs reads my input into a dictionary, formats it to have title formatting, and then outputs it to be read.  The assignment required we don't use something like `dictreader`.  I'd like to sort on last name, and then first name using `itemgetter`.  As you can see, I have a working version of the code using a `lambda` function, so I'd like to get the same result with the aforementioned `itemgetter` function.

```
import sys
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter, methodcaller


def data_2_dict(line):
    # constants
    NAME = 0
    ADDR = 1
    ADDR2 = 2
    CITY = 3
    STATE = 4
    ZIP = 5
    # split line and populate dictionary
    line = line.rstrip('\n')

    element = line.split(',')

    data_dict = {       
        'Name' : tuple(element[NAME].split(' ')),
        'Address' : element[ADDR],
        'Address2' : element[ADDR2],
        'City' : element[CITY],
        'State' : element[STATE],
        'Zip' : element[ZIP],
    }
    return format_data(data_dict)


def format_data(dict):
    for key, value in dict.iteritems():
        if key != 'Name' and key != 'State' and key != 'Zip':
            dict[key] = value.title()
        elif key == 'Name':
            dict[key] = (value[0].title(), value[1].title())

    return dict


def main():
    # gather in and out file, open objects
    infile = sys.argv[1]
    outfile = sys.argv[2]
    cust_list = []

    with open(infile, 'r') as myinfile:
        for line in myinfile.read().splitlines():
            data = data_2_dict(line)
            cust_list.append(data)

    # cust_list_sorted = sorted(cust_list, key=lambda key: (key['Name'][1], key['Name'][0]))
    cust_list_sorted = sorted(cust_list, key=itemgetter('Name'[1], 'Name'[0]))

    with open(outfile, 'w') as myoutfile:
        for line in cust_list_sorted:
            nameLine = 'Name: {0}, {1} ---\n'.format(line['Name'][1], line['Name'][0])
            myoutfile.write(nameLine)
            addrLine = '\tAddress: {0}, {1} {2}\n'.format(line['Address'],line['City'], line['State'])
            myoutfile.write(addrLine)
```

A line of input looks like this:

```
MICHELLE FULLER,265 MADEIRA AVE,,CHILLICOTHE,OH,00045
```

And a line of output should look like this:

```
Name: Fuller, Michelle ---
    Address: 265 Madeira Ave, Chillicothe OH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with `itemgetter`, which returns a callable that *fetches item from its operand*, because what you want it to do is *fetching item 0 from item "Name" from its operand*.

If you have to use `itemgetter`, you can just split and store "FirstName" and "LastName" in the dictionary and then use `itemgetter("LastName", "FirstName")`.

Answer (score 2):

(This is mostly an expansion of [satoru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31887647/1126841), prefaced with a mild rant about the lack of function composition in Python.)

If Python had a built-in function composition operator (say, `∘`), you could write:

```
cust_list_sorted = sorted(cust_list, key=itemgetter(1, 0)∘itemgetter('Name'))
```

Alas, Python does not (and will not, for the foreseeable future) have such an operator, meaning you *could* write

```
cust_list_sorted = sorted(cust_list,
                          key=lambda obj: itemgetter(1, 0)(itemgetter('Name')(obj))
```

but that's clearly worse than

```
cust_list_sorted = sorted(cust_list, key=lambda obj: obj['Name'][::-1])
```

(which is slightly shorter than the version you already have).

The problem is that `itemgetter` cannot drill down into a nested data structure. If you flatten your object like so:

```
data_dict = {       
    'FirstName' : element[NAME].split(' ')[0],
    'LastName' : element[NAME].split(' ')[1],
    'Address' : element[ADDR],
    'Address2' : element[ADDR2],
    'City' : element[CITY],
    'State' : element[STATE],
    'Zip' : element[ZIP],
}
```

*then* you could use `itemgetter` with

```
cust_list_sorted = sorted(cust_list, key=itemgetter('LastName', 'FirstName'))
```

Comment: It's not hard to implement `composition` ourselves though, and there are libraries that provide *meta* functions like this.

Comment: The beauty of a composition operator is that it would be less verbose than something like `compose(itemgetter(1,0), itemgetter('Name'))`, and could be implemented at a low enough level to be more efficient than a user-defined callable.

Comment: (`itemgetter('Name')` itself is easily implemented with `lambda obj: obj['Name']`, but it was introduced as an efficient alternative to the `lambda` expression.)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
cust_list_sorted = sorted(
    cust_list, key=lambda c, name=itemgetter('Name'): (name(c)[1], name(c)[0]))
```

This creates an `itemgetter` for `'Name'` and then uses it in a `lambda` that returns the tuple in the reverse order of `(lastname, firstname)`.